# modx minishop2 msImportExport не правильно читает csv-файл с товарами

Tags: modx, импорт, minishop2

В modx revolution 2.6.1 есть модуль minishop2 с надстройкой над ним msImportExport. Есть csv-файл с товарами : [csv-файл с категориями (иерархия) и товарами](https://yadi.sk/i/UD9g83603W8WPw) (Здесь урезанная версия файла). Как мне его импортировать правильно через msImportExport.

Вот визуальная картинка файла (здесь можно понять что к чему):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я вроде в настройках импорта всё правильно прописываю, но из 1500 товаров закачанными считаются только 20. И категории не по названию, а c1, c34 и т.д. Как мне поступить?

Answer (score 0):

Обязательные поля не указали и обязательно заполните поля, по которым проверяете товары на уникальность.
документация: https://modstore.pro/packages/import-and-export/msimportexport